# php timezone messing with javascript time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime, timeago

I'm using the [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com) plugin to update the time of posts automatically. It makes time like `05-08-2014 15:02:39` to `5 minutes ago`.

The problem is, the javascript uses client's clock for time. I'm from Bangladesh, Asia. But in php the default timezone varies from server to server. I'm outputting the format `05-08-2014 15:02:39` in PHP to convert it into something like `5 mintues ago` using the TimeAgo plugin.

Because server's timezone is different, instead of showing `less than a minute ago` on a recent post, it shows `nn hours ago`. If the server is american, it shows `11 hours ago`, if it's indian, the time shows `30 minutes ago`. How do I fix it?

Comment: Output the current time on the server to the page via PHP, and compare the date of the post to that, instead of the client time.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't understand. How will that solve the issue of timeago plugin using client's time?

Comment: As stated on the TimeAgo project page: Are you concerned about time zone support? Don't be. Timeago handles this too. As long as your timestamps are in ISO 8601 format and include a full time zone designator (±hhmm), everything should work out of the box regardless of the time zone that your visitors live in.

Comment: @Wulf I don't think my timestamps are in "ISO 8601". I don't even know what that is. Can you please explain?

Comment: See my answer below. ISO 8601 is for example '2014-08-05T11:29:30+0200'. The last part (+0200) is the hour difference to UTC, from which TimeAgo will calculate the correct timezone difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the TimeAgo project page:

> Are you concerned about time zone support? Don't be. Timeago handles
>   this too. As long as your timestamps are in ISO 8601 format and
>   include a full time zone designator (±hhmm), everything should work
>   out of the box regardless of the time zone that your visitors live in.

So echo the dates server side with `date('c',$timestamp)` and everything should work fine.